# Sum of low rank tensors

Tags: tensors, tensor-rank

How high can the sum of $k$ low rank $m\times m\times\dots \times m$ tensors of rank $t$ be? Is there a good upper bound?

Comment: Better than $\min\{m,kt\}$ you mean? Good in what sense?

Comment: You should **NOT** change the question after people have posted answers. If you have a different question, then post it as a separate question. ... For an upper bound for the rank of a sum of tensors: the sum has rank at most $kt$, and at most the maximum rank of an $m \times \dotsm \times m$ tensor: $r \leq \max(kt,r_{\max})$. But that $r_{\max}$ value is currently unknown in almost all cases. One of the only known cases is with three factors, $r_{\max}(m \times m \times m) = \binom{m+1}{2}$ for $m \geq 4$, or $=5$ for $m=3$.

Answer (score 1):

Rank $t$ means $t$ (but no more) linearly independent rows/columns. If those $t$ that are linearly independent in the first matrix are also linearly independent to $t$ of those independent in the second one, you get rank $2t$, and so on.

Therefore, your answer is $r_{MAX} = \min \{ m, kt \}$.

Without knowing anything more about these matrices, their sum will have rank anywhere between $0$ and $r_{MAX}$.

Answer (score 1):

The best upper bound is $\min\{m, kt\}$. This bound can be realised.

For $1 \leq i \leq k$, let $E_i$ be the $m\times m$ matrix with ones in the $(i-1)k+1, (i-1)k+2, \dots, ik$ entries on the main diagonal (all of the numbers taken $\operatorname{mod} m$ so that they are elements of $\{1, \dots, m\}$) and zeroes elsewhere. Note that each $E_i$ has rank $k$ (provided $k \leq m$) and the sum of these matrices has rank $\min\{kt, m\}$.